# JSON Data formatting for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts

I have a json object as shown below. I would like it to groupBy based on a specific property say "SEX" and pass it to highcharts such that I have only one xAxis category for "TIME" and chart should look like below:  [image]

```
[{"TIME":"2017-09-15","SEX":"MALE","ARIZONA":483280000.0,"IDAHO":6624960.0,"RATE":98.6291686272},
{"TIME":"2017-09-15","SEX":"FEMALE","ARIZONA":1034350000.0,"IDAHO":32409500.0,"RATE":96.8666697274},
{"TIME":"2017-09-16","SEX":"MALE","ARIZONA":482379000.0,"IDAHO":9578100.0,"RATE":98.0144001036},
{"TIME":"2017-09-16","SEX":"FEMALE","ARIZONA":1052960000.0,"IDAHO":40686800.0,"RATE":96.1359744871},
{"TIME":"2017-09-17","SEX":"FEMALE","ARIZONA":1052530000.0,"IDAHO":41476900.0,"RATE":96.0593301937},
{"TIME":"2017-09-17","SEX":"MALE","ARIZONA":1052590000.0,"IDAHO":41479900.0,"RATE":96.0893301937},]
```

How do we achieve it for the above JSON format..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use `filter` method in order to obtain two arrays: one for `male` and another for `female` entities.

Then use `map` method in order to obtain `dates`, `femaleRates` and `maleRates` **arrays**.

```js
let array=[{"TIME":"2017-09-15","SEX":"MALE","ARIZONA":483280000.0,"IDAHO":6624960.0,"RATE":98.6291686272}, {"TIME":"2017-09-15","SEX":"FEMALE","ARIZONA":1034350000.0,"IDAHO":32409500.0,"RATE":96.8666697274}, {"TIME":"2017-09-16","SEX":"MALE","ARIZONA":482379000.0,"IDAHO":9578100.0,"RATE":98.0144001036}, {"TIME":"2017-09-16","SEX":"FEMALE","ARIZONA":1052960000.0,"IDAHO":40686800.0,"RATE":96.1359744871}, {"TIME":"2017-09-17","SEX":"FEMALE","ARIZONA":1052530000.0,"IDAHO":41476900.0,"RATE":96.0593301937}, {"TIME":"2017-09-17","SEX":"MALE","ARIZONA":1052590000.0,"IDAHO":41479900.0,"RATE":96.0893301937}];
let males=array.filter(a=>a.SEX=='MALE');
let females=array.filter(a=>a.SEX=='FEMALE');
let dates=males.map(a=>a.TIME);
let malesRates=males.map(a=>a.RATE);
let femaleRates=females.map(a=>a.RATE);
console.log(dates);
console.log(malesRates);
console.log(femaleRates);
```

The last step is to display data in your **chart**.

```js
let array=[{"TIME":"2017-09-15","SEX":"MALE","ARIZONA":483280000.0,"IDAHO":6624960.0,"RATE":98.6291686272}, {"TIME":"2017-09-15","SEX":"FEMALE","ARIZONA":1034350000.0,"IDAHO":32409500.0,"RATE":96.8666697274}, {"TIME":"2017-09-16","SEX":"MALE","ARIZONA":482379000.0,"IDAHO":9578100.0,"RATE":98.0144001036}, {"TIME":"2017-09-16","SEX":"FEMALE","ARIZONA":1052960000.0,"IDAHO":40686800.0,"RATE":96.1359744871}, {"TIME":"2017-09-17","SEX":"FEMALE","ARIZONA":1052530000.0,"IDAHO":41476900.0,"RATE":96.0593301937}, {"TIME":"2017-09-17","SEX":"MALE","ARIZONA":1052590000.0,"IDAHO":41479900.0,"RATE":96.0893301937}];
let males=array.filter(a=>a.SEX=='MALE');
let females=array.filter(a=>a.SEX=='FEMALE');
let dates=males.map(a=>a.TIME);
let malesRates=males.map(a=>a.RATE);
let femaleRates=females.map(a=>a.RATE);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories:dates
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Males',
        data: malesRates
    }, {
        name: 'Females',
        data:femaleRates
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have one more question , actually my JSON data has a lot many districts[Arizona,Idaho,NY,AU....] for which I would like to create separate data series to be fed into highcharts. Is there any other way to reduce writing the map methods for all of them(200 of them)..??